# Doctrine2 - How can i make a relationship with string column

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I having a following issue, I need to make a relationship with two tables, but with no regular id, i need to use strings column. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sigtap_tb_procedimento")
 */
class Procedimento
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ExcecaoCompatibilidade", mappedBy="procedimento_restricao")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="co_procedimento_restricao", referencedColumnName="co_procedimento")
     */
    private $restricoes;

}
```

And another Entity

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sigtap_rl_excecao_compatibilidade") 
 */
class ExcecaoCompatibilidade
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Procedimento", inversedBy="restricoes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="co_procedimento_restricao", referencedColumnName="co_procedimento")
     */
    private $procedimento_restricao;
}
```

co_procedimento_restricao and co_procedimento_restricao are string type, The relation does not working. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your relation needs to reference a primary key in the other table.
May be I misunderstood your question but cant you reference the id collumn the relationship like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ExcecaoCompatibilidade", mappedBy="procedimento_restricao")
 */
private $restricoes;
```

---

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Procedimento", inversedBy="restricoes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="co_procedimento_restricao", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $procedimento_restricao;
```

Take a look here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

### using one-to-many relations with doctrine

The side using `@OneToMany` is always the **inverse** side of a relation from doctrine's pov ( possibly *not* what you consider being the inverse side ) and never has a join-column definition.

Remove the `@JoinColumn` annotation from `class Procedimento`.

`@OneToMany` has to use **mappedBy** and `@ManyToOne` (the **owning** side) uses **inversedBy**.

The join-column (or join-table) definition has to be on the owning side together with `@ManyToOne`.

When using a join-column the name of this column (which will be added to the table of the owning side entity aka the side being "many") will be specified by `name="column_name"` and the referenced foreign key to store in there is the `referencedColumnName="id"`definition of the `@JoinColum` annotation.

---